# how prevent whitespaces jquery keycode

Tags: jquery

I am using a syntax like this

```
if(e.keycode  == 17 ....
   e.preventDefault()
```

and works for all keys controls, alts, tabs and etc all but one the space which the keycode is 38 I want to prevent the user from typing whitespaces in a textbox

Comment: Check if `return false` works

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent user to type white space like this
just return `false` if keycode is `32` otherwise return `true`

```
$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/drvJD/)

Note: You have mentioned Key code 38 but this is for `UP` arrow key not for `Space`

Here is the list of [Key Code](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), but unfortunately author didn't include the space's Key code in this list :)

Comment: I realized that i used the wrong keycode. Thanks for the answers!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do so .
please check my sample here . 
http://jsfiddle.net/SinPride/9P29p/

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name">
<script>
$('#txt_name').keypress(function( e ) {
    if(e.which === 32) 
        return false;
});
</script>
```